# Tools to validate SDF files with

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm following the Gazebo tutorials on making a model. I decided to manually write the SDF file instead of copy pasting from the tutorial, so that I would learn better. I am now attempting to load the file in Gazebo and I get the following error:

```
Error [parser.cc:292] Error parsing XML in file [/home/mkhoory/gazebo/models/box.sdf]: Error reading end tag.
[Err] [Server.cc:391] Unable to read sdf file[models/box.sdf]
```

My question is: is there a tool I can use to validate the SDF file? I can't seem to find anyone mentioning any tool, and the error message from gazebo is unhelpful because it doesn't give me a line number in the very least.

Really all I want is the line number of where the problem is for when I load it with gazebo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15485/tools-to-validate-sdf-files-with/) by [9a3eedi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3072/9a3eedi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found a useful tool (xmllint) to make sure all of my SDF file are valid. It's actually a general tool for XML files, so it also works for config files for example.

Just run, for example:

> xmllint ~/.gazebo/models/ground_plane/model.sdf

If you just get the content of the file as output, then your SDF file is valid, otherwise you'd get errors.

It helps a lot. But I still run into issues that are specific to SDF files, so if there's a better tool it'll be great.

---

Originally posted by [9a3eedi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3072/9a3eedi/) with karma: 11 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0